# DocuSign: Use API to send signing requests and signing this document automatically myself

Tags: docusignapi

I using the default envelope creation to request a signature like:

```
\"recipients\":{
    \"signers\":[
      {
        \"email\":\"$email\",
        \"name\":\"$name\",
        \"recipientId\":\"1\",
        \"tabs\":{
          \"signHereTabs\":[
            {
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"xPosition\":\"65\",
              \"yPosition\":\"180\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"2\"
            },
```

I cannot find how I can tell the envelop that I want to set my own signature on the first page and have this done automatically rather than routing the document to myself first before sending it onwards.

Thanks, T

Comment: What exactly do you mean when you say you want to set your own signature and have it done automatically?  Do you mean have the system automatically sign for you?  If so you can't do that, but I'm curious what exactly you are trying to accomplish...

Comment: I am using PHP to distribute documents of which the first page is an intro letter which I would like to sign before sending. But I don't want to be the first signer otherwise I have to sign 300 documents while I am already in charge of sending these documents out. It's a bit weird that I ask clients to sign electronically while my signature on the first page is not. Hence I would like to add some code in the envelop creation that includes the senders (mine) signature. It's on the envelop already as the sender, just not on the first page in the documents to sign.

Comment: So I guess I was expecting something like this to be supported:

    \"sender\":{
    \"signer\":[
      {
          \"signedTabs\":[
            {
              \"documentId\":\"1\",
              \"xPosition\":\"65\",
              \"yPosition\":\"180\",
              \"pageNumber\":\"1\"
            },

Comment: No as mentioned you can not do that, at least you can't automatically sign or have the system "place" your signed signature on a given location.  If you need your signature in there first why don't sign a document once then load that signed document as the base document that you send out to everyone else?